# Recolor an element after applying an effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, effects

I want to change the colors (kind of *recolor*) of an element **A** on which I apply an effect **E(x)**, such that the new colors will be based on the colors of the element after the effect **B=E(A)**. Does anyone know how to do it?

For example, let's consider a color gradient on which we apply a stamp effect. This last one will turn all the colors to black and white. Now I want to change the black to blue and the white to yellow, **but** if I apply *recolor* on the original object I will always get a black and white output. Instead, I want to change the colors **after** the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if the result of your effect is a black and white image like the stamp effect gives you (or the halftone effect in this case).

Original object:

[image: Original]

Halftone effect applied:

[image: Effects applied]

Create a blue rectangle underneath your black and white object. Select both, open the transparency panel and click "Make Mask". This will create an opacity mask from the black and white object:

[image: Opacity mask applied]

Add another rectangle below to color the white (now transparent) areas:

[image: Final recoulored object]

This is more of a workaround though. There's no easy way to recolor objects based on the result of effects.

Comment: Thanks, it is a workaround but it's the workaround that I was looking for. And it works just perfectly.